# Why does my drop down menu close when i try to use it

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to mimic this website (but with my own images): https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_band.htm#

Every time I click on more to try to go down to "merchandise", "Extras" or "media" it closes (unless I do it very quickly). How can I fix this?

I know there's probably a better way of doing the drop-down menu in HTML/CSS but this is the only way I know how.

```css
nav {
  background-color: black;
  height: 3rem;
  widows: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  border: 1px solid hotpink;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar li {
  border: 2px solid green;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar li a {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

section#header-image {
  background-image: url('images/sky.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

.moreArrow{
    height: 6px;
    width: 8px;
margin-left: 5px;
}


ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}

ul li:hover ul li a {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">band</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">tour</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">more<img src="images/arrow.png" alt="x" class="moreArrow"></a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Merchandise</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Extras</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav> <!--end of nav-->

  <section id="header-image">

    <div class="header-text">
      <h2>London</h2>
      <p>We killing it up in 'ere </p>
    </div>

  </section>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, i made a lil change on your HTML, in order to persist ':hover' state you need to put anything that it has to stay visible inside the hovered item, in this case, a 'span' tag (i did changed from an 'a' tag because you cant nest 'a' tags)

The css is pretty simple from this point, you hide the sub menu and display on hover, anything that its inside the span tag belongs to ':hover' state as well

```css
body {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    nav {
      width: 100vw;
      height: auto;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    nav ul.navbar {
      display: flex;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    nav ul.navbar > li {
      width: auto;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    nav ul.navbar > li a {
      display: inline-block;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
      border: 1px solid red;
      padding: 10px 30px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: auto;
    }
    nav ul.navbar > li span {
      display: inline-block;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
      border: 1px solid red;
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px 30px;
    }
    nav ul.navbar > li span:hover ul {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    nav ul.navbar > li span ul {
      display: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 38px;
      left: 0px;
      width: auto;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    nav ul.navbar > li span ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      list-style: none;
      width: 100%;
    }
    nav ul.navbar > li span ul li a {
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul class="navbar">
          <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">band</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">tour</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
          <li>
          <span class="more">more
            <ul rel=":D">
              <li><a href="#">Merchandise</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Extras</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
            </ul>
          </span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav> <!--end of nav-->
    </header>
```

Hope this helps